# Authorize ShareKit to share files with Flickr

Tags: macos, network-shares, flickr

I'm running Mac OSX, Mavericks. I want to upload an image on my Flickr account using the normal contextual popup (see attachment) but ShareKit is not authorizing it. My Flickr account is connected and active in System Preferences / Internet Accounts. I can't figure out how to make the authorization happen.

Thanks

[image]